# Efficient way to compute multiple euclidean distances Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, euclidean-distance

I am training my own self organizing map to cluster colorvalues. Now I want to make some sort of a [U-matrix](http://ars.els-cdn.com/content/image/1-s2.0-S0925231208004475-gr11.jpg) to show euclidean distances between the nodes and their direct neighbors. My problem now is, that my algorithm is quite unefficient!! There is certainly a way to compute this more efficiently?

```
function displayUmatrix(dims,weights) %#dims is [30 30], size(weights) = [900 3], 
                                      %#consisting of values between 1 and 0

hold on; 
axis off;
A = zeros(dims(1), dims(2), 3);
B = reshape(weights',[dims(1) dims(2) size(weights,1)]);
if size(weights,1)==3
    for i=1:dims(1)
        for j=1:dims(2)
            if i~=1
                if j~=1
                    A(i,j,:)=A(i,j,:)+(B(i,j,:)-B(i-1,j-1,:)).^2;
                end
                A(i,j,:)=A(i,j,:)+(B(i,j,:)-B(i-1,j,:)).^2;
                if j~=dims(2)
                    A(i,j,:)=A(i,j,:)+(B(i,j,:)-B(i-1,j+1,:)).^2;
                end
            end
            if i~=dims(1)
                if j~=1
                    A(i,j,:)=A(i,j,:)+(B(i,j,:)-B(i+1,j-1,:)).^2;
                end
                A(i,j,:)=A(i,j,:)+(B(i,j,:)-B(i+1,j,:)).^2;
                if j~=dims(2)
                    A(i,j,:)=A(i,j,:)+(B(i,j,:)-B(i+1,j+1,:)).^2;
                end
            end 
            if j~=1
                A(i,j,:)=A(i,j,:)+(B(i,j,:)-B(i,j-1,:)).^2;
            end
            if j~=dims(2)
                A(i,j,:)=A(i,j,:)+(B(i,j,:)-B(i,j+1,:)).^2;
            end
            C(i,j)=sum(A(i,j,:));
        end
    end
    D = flipud(C);
    maximum = max(max(D));
    D = D./maximum;
    imagesc(D)
else
    error('display function does only work on 3D input');
end
hold off;
drawnow;
```

end

Thanks, Max

Comment: I would suggest you use a 2D convolution kernel along each of the 3 dimensions to get the TOTAL distance between each point an ALL of its neighbours at once, and then square it. I'm not sure this is what you want, though, because in your code you square it at each step before adding the computed distance on. Still, you could do several convolutions on your B matrix, e.g. with the kernel [1 -1; 0 -1] to get, e.g., all the B(i, j, :) - B(i - 1, j + 1, :) in one go. (Someone please correct me if I've got that wrong). Not sure it'd be any faster though.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I would say this would in any way improve the readability of the code. I'll look it up in the Matlab documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate the (squared) distance of each point to its neigbor to the right by:

```
sum((B(:,1:end-1,:) - B(:,2:end,:)).^2, 3)
```

Similarly, you calculate the distance of each point to the point below, and on both diagonals. You don't have all those values for points on borders so you pad them with zeros. Then you add the distances and divide them by the number of neighbors a point has to get the average distance to all the neighbors.

Here is my code:

```
%calculate distances to neighbors
right = sum((B(:,1:end-1,:)- B(:,2:end,:)).^2, 3);
bottom = sum((B(1:end-1,:,:)- B(2:end,:,:)).^2, 3); zeros();
diag1 = sum((B(1:end-1,1:end-1,:)- B(2:end,2:end,:)).^2, 3);
diag2 = sum((B(2:end,2:end,:)- B(1:end-1,1:end-1,:)).^2, 3);

%pad them with zeros to the correct size
rightPadded = [right zeros(dim(1) , 1)];
leftPadded = [zeros(dim(1) , 1) right];

botomPadded = [bottom; zeros(1,dim(2))];
upPadded = [zeros(1,dim(2));bottom];

bottomRight = zeros(dim(1), dim(2));
bottomRight(1:end-1,1:end-1) = diag1;
upLeft = zeros(dim(1), dim(2));
upLeft(2:end,2:end) = diag1;

bottomLeft = zeros(dim(1), dim(2));
bottomLeft(1:end-1,2:end) = diag2;
upRight = zeros(dim(1), dim(2));
upRight(2:end,1:end-1) = diag2;

%add distances to all neighbors
sumDist = rightPadded + leftPadded + bottomRight + upLeft + bottomLeft + upRight;

%number of neighbors a point has
neighborNum = zeros(dim(1), dim(2)) + 8;
neighborNum([1 end],:) = 5;
neighborNum(:,[1 end]) = 5;
neighborNum([1 end],[1 end]) = 3;

%divide summed distance by number of neighbors
avgDist = sumDist./neighborNum;
```

It is all vectorized, so it should be faster than your version.
If you want the exact U-matrix, you can interleave the average distances with the neighboring distances.

Comment: Nicely done, thanks, that really helped a lot for time complexity!